# Sum of random variable and probability convergence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

For each $n \in N$ let{$X_{n,k} :1\le k \le n$}be IID random variables such that $0\le X_{n,k} \le C$ (same constant C for all n and k). Let $S_n =X_{n,1} +X_{n,2} +···+X_{n,n}$. Assume that $$ES_n \rightarrow \infty$$
Show that $S_n → ∞$ in probability.

For any k < $\infty$, $P{(S_n \le k)}→0$ as n→∞. I tried controlling the distance using Chebychev's inequality but I got no where. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

LLN: $\frac {S_n} n\to E(X_{nk})>0$ in probability. Hence $S_n\to \infty$ in probability.